# Use `sed` to replace text in code block with output of command at the top of the code block

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a markdown file that has snippets of code resembling the following example:

````
```
$ cat docs/code_sample.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Hello, world"
```
````

This means there there's a file at the location `docs/code_sample.sh`, whose contents is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Hello, world"
```

I'd like to parse the markdown file with `sed` (`awk` or `perl` works too) and replace the bottom section of the code snippet with whatever the above bash command evaluates to, for example whatever `cat docs/code_sample.sh` evaluates to.

Comment: So there will always be a 3-backtick line followed by a command such as `cat docs/code_sample.sh` with a leading `$ ` and then a blank line? And you want to replace everything from that first blank line to the closing 3 backticks with the output of the first command line, yes?

Comment: @PaulHodges, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sed-only solution is easier if you have the GNU version with an `e` command.

That said, here's a quick, simplistic, and kinda clumsy version I knocked out that doesn't bother to check the values of previous or following lines - it just assumes your format is good, and bulls through without any looping or anything else. Still, for my example code, it worked.

I started by making an `a`, a `b`, and an `x` that is the markup file.

````
$: cat a
#! /bin/bash
echo "Hello, World!"

$: cat b
#! /bin/bash
echo "SCREW YOU!!!!"

$: cat x
```
$ cat a

foo
   bar
" b a z ! "
```
```
$ cat b

foo
   bar
" b a z ! "
```
````

Then I wrote `s` which is the `sed` script.

````
$: cat s
#! /bin/env bash

sed -En '

 /^```$/,/^```$/ {

  # for the lines starting with the $ prompt
  /^[$] / {
    # save the command to the hold space
    x
    # write the ``` header to the pattern space
    s/.*/```/
    # print the fabricated header
    p
    # swap the command back in
    x
    # the next line should be blank - add it to the current pattern space
    N
    # first print the line of code as-is with the (assumed) following blank line
    p
    # scrub the $ (prompt) off the command
    s/^[$] //
    # execute the command - store the output into the pattern space
    e
    # print the output
    p
    # put the markdown footer back
    s/.*/```/
    # and print that
    p
  }

  # for the (to be discarded) existing lines of "content"
  /^[^`$]/d

}
' $*
````

It does the job and might get you started.

````
$: s x
```
$ cat a

#! /bin/bash
echo "Hello, World!"
```
```
$ cat b

#! /bin/bash
echo "SCREW YOU!!!!"
```
````

Lots of caveats - better to actually check that the `$` follows a line of backticks and is followed by a blank line, maybe make sure nothing bogus could be in the file to get executed... but this does what you asked, with (GNU) `sed`.

Good luck.

Comment: Note that it does not do in-place edits. This will output the alternate version of your source file to stdout for you to redirect into a temp file where you can look it over before you do anything else.

Comment: Accept the solution? Also, check out [this breakdown](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for more useful insights of how to actually use loops, and [this reference](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) for some complex examples, though they don't quite fit this circimstance. In particular, this section on [multiline techniques](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiline-techniques) might help.

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue!

````
perl -0777 -pe 's/(?<=```\n)^(\$ (.*)\n\n)(?^s:.*?)(?=```)/"$1".qx($2)/meg' < input > output
````

- `-0777` slurps the whole file into memory
- `-p` prints the input after processing
- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` works similarly to a substitution in `sed`
- `/g` replaces globally, i.e. as many times as it can
- `/m` makes `^` match start of each line instead of start of the whole input string
- `/e` evaluates the replacement as code
- ```` (?<=```\n) ```` means "preceded by three backquotes and a newline"
- `(?^s:.*?)` changes the behaviour of `.` to match newlines as well, so it matches (frugally because of the `*?`) the rest of the preformatted block
- ```` (?=```) ```` means "followed by three backquotes`
- `qx` runs the parameter in a shell and returns its output

Comment: With all these unintuitive options, it's no surprise Perl scripts are often teasingly called "write-only".

Comment: @DodgyCodeException: There are just three options, two of them rather standard. In a production code, I wouldn't use a one-liner, and would probably comment the regex using `/x`.

Comment: @choroba this almost works for me, though whenever `input` == `output` e.g. `... < file.md > file.md`, `file.md` will end up empty. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Output to a different file, then rename it.

Answer (score 1):

A rare case when use of getline would be appropriate:

````
$ cat tst.awk
state == "importing" {
    while ( (getline line < $NF) > 0 ) {
        print line
    }
    close($NF)
    state = "imported"
}

$0 == "```" { state = (state ? "" : "importing") }

state != "imported" { print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
````

See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for getline uses and caveats.